# Qt error , libtiff.so.4 not found

Tags: qt, opencv

I try to build an Qt-opencv application in Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit but it keeps warning that "libtiff.so.4, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)". How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you even have the library on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happened to me on Ubuntu 13.10 and I solved installing the libtiff4
You can do it by typing

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4
```

on terminal or using the synaptic manager